# SQLite Tool with Foreign Key support?

Tags: sqlite

Is there any tool for SQLite that allows data entry with foreign key lookup?

When writing code I often need to type in a few sample records into a table.  But this is a real pain when you have to enter raw id values instead of being able to make quick drop down selections.

For example if you have a classic "product" table could have foreign keys for size, color, and 10 other attributes.  I want to be able to start typing in a row to the product table and when the "size" column is selected I can choose from small medium or large instead of an integer.

I know SQLite requires a newer version for FK support, but this question assumes the support is there and is about a tool that uses FKs for quick/easy data entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navicat has this functionality.

After trying many (all?) SQLite management tools I can tell you this is a rare feature.  So Navicat costs a bit of money but if you want helper functionality to make it easy to enter foreign key values this might be the only game in town as of this date.

Answer (score 9):

[SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/) has this functionality. It's free (donations accepted) and actively developed.